# Create multiple screens iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

Which Xcode template do I select to build say facebook app ?

Is it an navigation based app? Or is it a windows app with multiple view screens?

I'm going to select the windows based template! Now howdy I add addition screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this kind of screen is not in UIKit.
Maybe someone has develop external framework for this.

You can do something like a UIView with UIImage or UIButton that manage events

Edit : **Three20 framework is what you search for**

Comment: How do you even know what K001 is trying to do? It's a mystery to me. He/she wants to know how to add "screens" to a window based template. I would think that reading the interface builder documentation would help in that regard, as apparently he/she is using IB. But judging from the question, K001 should also do some reading on iOS in general. I don't know if Three20 is the answer to his/her questions. Maybe so...

Comment: I have supposed (maybe wrong) that he wants to do something like the facebook app with a view with icons, each icons open a different view/"screen".

Comment: Probably. I just thought the question was not very informative and far too broad for a meaningful answer. But kudos to you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/URL_iPhone_OS_Overview/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007592

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/URL_Tools_for_iPhone_OS_Development/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007593